# How to style an embedded text?

Tags: flutter

i have a piece of code below and i wanted to style the text "From" differently, i.e, display it black and bold in colour. It should remain in the same format.

Thank you.

```
Text("From :" + " " + from, style: GoogleFonts.viga(
              color: Colors.blue[800],
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
              ),  /*TextStyle(color: Colors.blue[800],)*/
            ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `RichText` and `TextSpan` classes to achieve this behavior.

```dart
RichText(
  text: TextSpan(
    text: 'From:',
    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
    children: <TextSpan>[
      TextSpan(text: ' $from', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue[800])),

    ],
  ),
)
```

You can read more about it [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RichText-class.html)